# Disable scrolling up/down while paging iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I am trying to make a calendar type app (more complex in many ways), but one problem that I run into is that while trying to switch days via paging (all of my days appear on one scroll view loaded lazily, which is then paged to change the day), the view still scrolls up/down. While this isn't a huge thing, it is slightly annoying. Is there any way to disable user interaction in just the up/down direction, and only allow scrolling once the scrollview has settled on a page?

Thanks, and if something here doesn't make sense add a comment and I will be sure to clarify.

Comment: UIScrollView has its own delegate methods to handle this kind of things. You can combine them to recognize paging animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in one case in which i have to scroll it for horizontal position only !

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(YOUR_CONTENT_WIDTH, 0)];
// Pass 0 as in hieght will stop scrolling to vertical (up/down) position.
```

Hope this will solve your problem.